# How to handle multiple similar projects? Why?

Tags: project-management, productivity, time-management, multitasking

I currently have 4 projects under development. All of them related to the same product (hardware) but different after all (desktop, android and web environments).
That product, the hardware, is constantly changing, improving and thus all related software so there is no real "ending".

How should I manage time? Should I spend a few days on each project or try to dedicate time to all of them each day/week/month?

The relation between all the projects is clear, as they almost "do the same", but of course technologies, structure and philosophy are different (java, android, javascript) so I have to "change the chip". Should I minimize this chip switching?

Do you have experience in this kind of situation? When do you make more mistakes: after spending a few hours on X language (and switching to Y) or after some days? Any other drawback to consider based on your experience?

---

**EDIT:** flagged as duplicate. I don't think we are asking the same question. @Lacrymology's one focuses on tools/methods to keep track of what you were doing a week ago in certain project. But my question is not about that:
 - *Should I spend a few days on each project or try to dedicate time to all of them each day/week/month?*
 - *Should I minimize this chip switching?*
 - *When do you make more mistakes [..]?*
 - *Any other drawback to consider based on your experience?*

Comment: maybe abstract the actual interface to the hardware out into a common library, so when the hardware changes you only need to change a single library instead of going back to all projects using it

Comment: the interface is in fact common, but the data changes. For example, we add a new parameter, or a set of parameters the software must understand, validate, show in a human way... software must change hehe.